# Split string on "and" and a few symbols, but prevent split on hyphens if surrounded by digits

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds, preg-split, delimited

For some data processing I need to split a string into multiple items.
An example of an input string is:

```
'one, two & three and four-five 123-456'
```

Now, I need to separate this string into items, where possible delimiters are `,`, `&`,  (space), `and`, `-`. But, and this is the point where I'm stuck, it should not split on a `-` when it is between two numbers.

I am using PHP and `preg_split` to do the actual splitting, but I need a regex pattern to match the delimiters excluding the delimiter `-` when it is between two numbers (digits, but could also be `123-456`). Suppression of spaces around each item is done with `trim()` in PHP.

I am using the following regex pattern:

```
/(and|,|\s|&)|\D(-)\D/
```

The output (after using `preg_split`, etc) is:

```
[0] => one
[1] => two
[2] => three
[3] => fou
[4] => ive
[5] => 123-456
```

The working is correct, but it also takes the last and first letter of the surrounding text for the `-` delimiter. The item `123-456` is correct, since it should not match (and split with `preg_split`) on a `-` when it is immediately surrounded by a number.

Expected output is:

```
[0] => one
[1] => two
[2] => three
[3] => four
[4] => five
[5] => 123-456
```

Any help is appreciated, if any information is lacking let me know and I'll update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to use is [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (more generally known as lookaround):

```
/and|,|\s|&|(?<!\d)-(?!\d)/
```

What this will do is exactly what the name implies - look around to check if the specified pattern is matched, *without matching it*. In this case, it'll only match a `-` that isn't surrounded on both sides by numeric characters (the `\d`s), but the *match* will only be the `-` itself.

In this case, `(?<!\d)` is a *negative lookbehind* - it will look backwards to see if the immediately preceding string *does not* match the pattern. If it does, it reports the match as failed and moves on. Likewise, `(?!\d)` is a *negative lookahead* - it does precisely the same thing, but in the opposite direction. Because the `-` is sandwiched between them, the effect is "match only a `-` if it does not have numeric characters on both sides".

Comment: Thank you. This solved my question. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes when it lets me. Out of interest, what's the reason for difference in notation for the first part? It works exactly the same as mine, but does it do something else?

Comment: The last alternation side should be `(?<!\d)-(?!\d)` otherwise it doesn't match leading and trailing `-`

Comment: @revo: Good catch. Edited.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz Thanks for the extra explanation. Can you explain why do you not need the matching `()` around the first part `and|,|\s|&`? Also, I'm trying to understand this as much as possible, @revo, what does it mean that leading and trailing `-` would not get matched?

Comment: Because the simple `()` (brackets) is a _capture group_ - in your scenario, it wasn't needed, so I deleted it. Let's say you had a separator that could be either `and` or `andson`. Then, for instance, you could do something like `/and(son)?|foo|bar/` - the brackets are used to "group" the `son`, so it's operated on as a group by the `?` (optional) quantifier. This regex would be equivalent to `/and|andson|foo|bar/`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to safeguard hyphens surrounded by digits, is to leverage `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` -- basically you match and discard substrings which should be disqualified.  The lookarounds pattern in Sebastian's answer takes 10 steps to parse the string.

The following pattern will take 7 steps to parse the string. I've consolidated the in single delimiting characters and whitespace sequence in a character class and added a one-or-more quantifier to improve performance and reduce the number of explosions.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4eSId))

```
$string = 'one, two & three and four-five 123-456';
var_export(
    preg_split('/\d-\d(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|and|[\s,&-]+/i', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'one',
  1 => 'two',
  2 => 'three',
  3 => 'four',
  4 => 'five',
  5 => '123-456',
)
```

To be fair, `/and|[\s,&]+|(?<!\d)-(?!\d)/i` will also parse the input string in 7 steps, so it comes down to pattern brevity or personal preference. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eq6KZ))

```
var_export(
    preg_split('/and|[\s,&]+|(?<!\d)-(?!\d)/i', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```